# how to add checkbox List in custom block in Piranha CMS

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, checkboxlist, piranha-cms

I want to add checkbox List that load data from outer list for select in an custom Block that fine works.
after version 8.3 ability of add enum implemented as per @håkan-edling said.

sample of Code for implementing checkboxlist field in piranha 10

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.